# Join values of two hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question how i can merge the contain of two hashes for example

```
[
  {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:rfc=>"This rfc is invalid"}},
  {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:email=>"This email is invalid"}}
]

[
  {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>true, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}},
  {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>false, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}
]
```

and get one only value for alert in each user

```
[
  {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:rfc=>"This rfc is invalid", :income_in_the_mean=>true, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}},
  {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:email=>"This email is invalid",:income_in_the_mean=>false, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}
]
```

Comment: Those aren't two hashes. They are two arrays of hashes.

Comment: Can we assume two hashes with the same *user* always have the same array index? (Assuming you want to merge hashes with the same *user*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ruby on Rails, you can do something like this:

```
h1 = [
  {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:rfc=>"This rfc is invalid"}},
  {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:email=>"This email is invalid"}}
]

h2 = [
  {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>true, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}},
  {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>false, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}
]

(h1+h2).group_by{|h| h[:user]}.values.map{|v| v.reduce(:deep_merge)}
```

The output is:

```
[
  {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:rfc=>"This rfc is invalid", :income_in_the_mean=>true, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}},
  {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:email=>"This email is invalid", :income_in_the_mean=>false, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}
]
```

<s>Keep in mind that it will work only if you have exactly two hashes for each user.</s>

I have updated my answer thanks to @tadman and @3limin4t0r

Comment: Instead of using `v[0].deep_merge(v[1])` you could also use `v.reduce(:deep_merge)`, which also works for group sizes other than 2.

Comment: You can also do `.values.map { |v|` to skip the key if the keys aren't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, plain old good ruby solution:

```
[h1 + h2].each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {} }) do |h, acc|
  acc[h[:user]].merge!(h) { |_, v1, v2| v1.merge(v2) rescue v1 }
end.values
```

Comment: I'd personally go for `rescue v2` instead of `rescue v1`, since it's more consistent with the `#merge!` method that defaults to the new value, not the old value. Of course this depends on the use-case.

Comment: @3limin4t0r If those are not hashes, key is `:user` and (check the accumulating strategy) `v1 ≡ v2` :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple index based approach might look something like this:

```
array_1 = [
  {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:rfc=>"This rfc is invalid"}},
  {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:email=>"This email is invalid"}}
]

array_2 = [
  {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>true, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}},
  {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>false, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}
]

array_1.zip(array_2).map { |item_1, item_2| item_1.deep_merge(item_2) }
#=> [
#   {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:rfc=>"This rfc is invalid", :income_in_the_mean=>true, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}},
#   {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:email=>"This email is invalid", :income_in_the_mean=>false, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}
# ]
```

Using [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) and Rails [`#deep_merge`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_merge). For this to work the arrays have to be the same size and the elements to merge must be on the same index position.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure-Ruby solution.

```
arr = [
  [
    {:user=>"Maria",
     :alerts=>{:rfc=>"This rfc is invalid"}},
    {:user=>"Juan",
     :alerts=>{:email=>"This email is invalid"}}
  ],
  [
    {:user=>"Maria",
       :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>true, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}},
    {:user=>"Juan",
       :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>false, :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}
  ]
]
```

```
arr.flatten.group_by { |h| h[:user] }.map do |user,a|
  { user: user, alerts: a.reduce({}) { |h,g| h.merge(g[:alerts]) } }
end
  #=> [{:user=>"Maria",
  #     :alerts=>{:rfc=>"This rfc is invalid", :income_in_the_mean=>true,
  #               :credit_in_the_mean=>true}},
  #    {:user=>"Juan",
  #     :alerts=>{:email=>"This email is invalid", :income_in_the_mean=>false,
  #               :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}]
```

Note:

```
arr.flatten.group_by { |h| h[:user] }
  #=> {"Maria"=>[{:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:rfc=>"This rfc is invalid"}},
  #              {:user=>"Maria", :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>true,
  #                 :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}],
  #    "Juan" =>[{:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:email=>"This email is invalid"}},
  #              {:user=>"Juan", :alerts=>{:income_in_the_mean=>false,
  #                 :credit_in_the_mean=>true}}]}
```

`arr` can be of any size, of course.